# Wortdefinition Kindersprache "Rattergewehr" und "Schießgewehr"

Tags: etymology, baby-talk

Mein Sohn möchte wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen einem Rattergewehr und einem Schießgewehr ist.

Da ich mir nicht ganz sicher bin was der Unterschied ist, frage ich hier noch mal nach.

Entweder gibt es zwei disjunkte Kategorien Schießgewehr und Rattergewehr oder Schießgewehr ist die Oberklasse und Rattergewehr ist die Unterklasse davon.

In Wikipdeia gibt es zwar eine Weiterleitung von Schießgewehr zu Gewehr, aber vielleicht gibt es doch noch einen Unterschied.

Comment: Schießgewehr macht "bumm" (wenn es etwas macht), Rattergewehr macht "ratatatata", oder? Wenn dem so ist, dann wäre das Schießgewehr das Hyperonym. - Suchmaschinen zeigen bei "Rattergewehr" Bilder von sehr gruselig aussehenden Plastik-Maschinengewehren.

Comment: Gehört das übrigens überhaupt hierher? Oder eher in https://spielwarenkunde.stackexchange.org ?

Comment: Das verhält sich so wie die Muhkuh zum Rind oder wie die Schnatterente zur ... und so weiter, nur eben angewandt auf Mordspielzeug ...

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen die Ziege Meckmeckmeck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon verrät mir, dass ein Rattergewehr ein Kinderspielzeug ist, dass das Geräusch einer automatischen Waffe immitiert.

Schießgewehr ist eine veraltete Bezeichnung für Gewehr. Das Wort Schießgewehr kann für ein Spielzeuggewehr verwendet werden; für eine moderne, automatische Waffe passt es nur bedingt.

Rattergewehre sind aber immer Spielzeuggewehre, so dass Rattergewehr keine Oberkategorie von Schießgewehr ist.